# Shortcut to change editor's global font size

Tags: pycharm

I can change font size on a per-file basis in PyCharm (4.5.2) by using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Mousewheel</kbd>.

Is there anyway to set up a shortcut to change the font size of all files?

Right now, the only way to do that is `Settings` > `Editor` > `Color & Fonts` > `Fonts`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no such shortcut in PyCharm out of the box. It's easy to implement in a plugin, though.